# window.innerWidth returning same value on different displays

Tags: javascript

I have a small display monitor connected through a VGA connector to my laptop, running Windows. The display is identical in both of them. I am now running a small piece of JavaScript to determine the width of the smaller screen from the laptop -

```js
alert(window.innerWidth);
```

The same width of 441 is being shown for both screens. Is there a way to write the code/change the configuration in such a way so that the width of each display is shown in the alert box?

Comment: This seems to be working pretty well when changing the devices... Can't see why it would not on your code ?  

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_innerheight_crossbrowser

Comment: `I have a small display monitor connected through a VGA connector to my laptop, running Windows.`  JS works on your browser then alerts the width. monitor connected through VGA just shows whatever is on the laptop screen .

Answer (score 0):

The `window.innerWidth` returns the current window width (as expected). It changes dynamically when you're resizing the window. If the value persists, it means that the width hasn't changed, or the resolutions are the same. Given the small value (441), I presume that the window isn't maximized, so when you are moving it to the other screen, the value is actually the same.

See the documentation for more info: [innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth)

Answer (score 0):

The alert only shows the innerWidth of the *first choosen* device width. To show the width *all the time*, you have to add the event listener **resize** to the **window**:

```
function showInnerWidth() {
    console.log(window.innerWidth);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", showInnerWidth);
```

**Do not use alert**, because then it will alert all the time you resize the window.